# How to implement GeoLocator StreamController and get Data through screens - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I implemented this package https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator but I don't know how to use StreamSubscription.

```
class LocationService{

  UserLocation _userLocation;
  
  StreamController<UserLocation> locationUserController;

  var geolocator = Geolocator();
  var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10);

  LocationService(){

    geolocator.getPositionStream(locationOptions).listen(
    (Position position) {
        if (position != null){
          locationUserController.add(UserLocation(
            latitude: position.latitude,
            longitude: position.longitude
          ));
        }
    });
  }
}
```

I implemented GeoLocator.That set values into a model class **UserLocation**.

```
class UserLocation{
  final double latitude;
  final double longitude;

  UserLocation({this.latitude, this.longitude});
}
```

How I access this **UserLocation** every time that values change?

I need to acess this data in **MapsScreen**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //my try. I don't know what I'm doing
    //StreamProvider<UserLocation>(
    //  create: (_) => LocationService().locationUserController,
    //)
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'UnMatch',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: ThemeColor.nero,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: {
        '/home' : (context) => MapScreen(),
        '/login' : (context) => Login()
      }
    );  
  }
}
```

Can you explain and insert in the code how should I do? I'm very confused with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kinda surprising to see this, but i saw a youtube video with the exact code you need explained **step-by-step.**

[Here's the video by FilledStacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdBUe_NP-BI)